# Im having problems with geting data from MySQL to my java project

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to make a project in java but I'm having problems with MySQL, after trying to get the material inside the table I get this error message:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table' at line 1

```
String sql = "SELECT Name, OS, Disk, Office, Serialnomain, Serialnotast, Serialnoscreen, Serialnomouse FROM table ";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your name from table to anything else and will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

table is a [reserved word](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/) in mariadb

so rename your table and it will run

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Language has some keywords which you should not use in your statement, table is one of them just rename your table to myTable